# Implicit XAML Style stops working when I base it upon a Key-ed version

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an implicit WPF Control style (for a control based on `MultiSelector`).  My problem is that it only gets picked up implicitly when I define it all as *one single style*.  If I instead give it a key and then try to make an implicit version based upon *that*, it stops working.

To illustrate here's an abbreviated version of the style when it works, all as one implicit style.  (The control is meant to show shapes and images on a `Canvas`, allow the user to select, manipulate them, etc)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:LayerView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource LayerViewStyle}">

    <Style.Resources>

        <!-- Any SdkLine object within the LayerView should use our custom LineControl -->

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sdk:SdkLine}">
            <ctrl:LineControl P1="{Binding P1}" P2="{Binding P2}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Any ItemsControl within the LayerView is presumed to use a Canvas -->

        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}" >
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas  IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

If I do it like the above, all my shapes show up beautifully;  The implicit styles within the Resources section get picked up.

And here is how I broke it:  I gave it a key and then made it implicit just one line below.  (I won't repeat the whole style.

```
<!-- Named version of full style -->

<Style x:Key="SpecialLayerViewStyle" 
    TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:LayerView}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource LayerViewStyle}">
 ... (rest of the above style here) ....
</Style

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:LayerView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource SpecialLayerViewStyle}"/>
```

Suddenly, none of those implicit styles within the `Resources` section get picked up.  With no other changes.

Shouldn't the second version have identical behavior as the first?  Is there some WPF styling/templating rule I am missing here?

**[EDIT]** In answer to the questions posed in the comments:

The control does override metadata to make implicit styling work

```
static LayerView()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(LayerView), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LayerView)));
}
```

The style is defined in a resource dictionary that lives alongside the control.  This dictionary is included by any XAML code that tries to use the countrol (in a `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>` section).

When I made my changes (to give the previous version a key and then define the "implicit" version) I put that implicit version immediately below it in the very same resource dictionary.  So any UI that was seeing the implicit version before should also be seeing the named version and new the implicit "based on" version.

**[/EDIT]**

Comment: Does your control have a static constructor that sets the default style key? How do you try to apply the style to the control? Where are the styles and the control defined? Please update your question with all necessary details.

Comment: I have edited the post to answer your questions

Answer (score 0):

When you define a `static` constructor that calls `DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata`, you should also define a default `Style` for your custom control in a resource dictionary called `themes/generic.xaml`.

So create a folder called "themes" at the root of your project and add resource dictionary called "generic.xaml" to it. In the resource dictionary you then define the default style for the control (without any `x:Key`):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:LayerView}">
...
</Style>
```

The styling of your control should then work the same as for any other control.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt to help me.   However my implicit style is already visible to the XAML that uses the control it styles.  That was true before I made my changes and after.  WPF picks up any implicit style as long as it is visible XAML that uses the control it styles.  In other words, there is no requirement for the style to be located in a dictionary specifically  named "generic.xaml" in a "themes" folder).

Comment: Yes, because otherwise it doesn't have any default style by definition. Either remove the static constructor or add a default style to `themes/generic.xaml`. Your current setup is invalid.

Comment: I'm sorry but it *does* have a default style by definition.  One that is clearly visible to all my uses of the control via included resource dictionaries..  That's why the default style worked before.  I didn't change the location of anything.  All I did was make the default style be based on a key-ed on

Comment: No. There is a difference between a default style and an implicit one.

Comment: I initially wrote here, "What is the difference?" but (after it occurred to me that there's thing called Google...) I now realize I have stumbled across a distinction I had never understood before, not in years of doing WPF.  I thought implicit was the same thing as default.  I  do see what you are saying now.  I have some reading to do.  Thank you